# 560k 2% resistor alternative

Tags: resistors, resistance, alternatives

I need a 560k 2% resistor which has 5 bands, I am not getting it online.

The available resistors online are 560k 1W, 2W.
Which one should I choose?

Will one these resistors work as it should be instead of the existing 560k 2%?

Comment: What tolerance are the online ones? If 2% or better, they are fine. If 5% and you're desperate, buy several and measure until you find one within 2%.

Comment: What does the resistor do and for what application it is? Does it matter if it is an highly inductive wirewound resistors, or should it be something else?

Comment: The resistance is in IFB washing machine, the error washing machine shows is Low Ac voltage , and this resistor needs to be replaced

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a 1% resistor. 2% is not that common these days. You should use parts of adequate power rating (higher is okay).

If you can't find 560k 1% (I see plenty in stock, depending on wattage etc.) you can use 562k 1% (a standard E96 series value).

560k 2% is guaranteed to be somewhere between 549k and 571k.

562k 1% is guaranteed to be somewhere between 556k and 568k, so well
within the same range.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped,